# Error al ejecutar el comando npm installl

Tags: npm

**Error que muestra npm:**

> npm ERR! Windows_NT 6.1.7601 npm ERR! argv "C:\Program
>   Files\nodejs\node.exe" "C:\Program
>   Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\bin\npm-cli.js" "install" "-g"
>   "@angular/cli" npm ERR! node v6.11.4 npm ERR! npm  v3.10.10 npm ERR!
>   code ECONNRESET
>
> npm ERR! network tunneling socket could not be established,
>   cause=connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:80 npm ERR! network This is most
>   likely not a problem with npm itself npm ERR! network and is related
>   to network connectivity. npm ERR! network In most cases you are behind
>   a proxy or have bad network settings. npm ERR! network npm ERR!
>   network If you are behind a proxy, please make sure that the npm ERR!
>   network 'proxy' config is set properly.  See: 'npm help config' npm
>   ERR! Windows_NT 6.1.7601 npm ERR! argv "C:\Program
>   Files\nodejs\node.exe" "C:\Program
>   Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\bin\npm-cli.js" "install" "-g"
>   "@angular/cli"

Comment: Es un error de red. Quizás tienes problemas de conexión o npm tiene problemas para resolver el paquete. ¿Podrías poner el nombre del paquete que quieres instalar?

Answer (score 0):

El error te dice que el servidor no esta respondiendo. Configura la ruta del proxy para que funcione

Prueba lo siguiente, en una terminal ejecuta

```
npm config set strict-ssl false

npm config set registry "http://registry.npmjs.org/"

npm --proxy "http://usuario:contrasenha+&{{'@servidorproxy:8080" install -g @angular/cli
```

Ingresa tu usuario y contrasenha.
Y para saber la ip de salida de tu proxy, desde navegador google chrome:

*Configuración de tu navegador en herramientas* >> *Abrir configuración de proxy* >> *Configuración de LAN* >> *copia la dirección que te tira en servidor proxy*

> El puerto por defecto es el 8080 pero dentro de la configuración LAN
>   lo puedes configurar